# passing image with post request in rspec (paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, rspec-rails

```
Failure/Error: post :create, Devise.token_authentication_key => @foo.authentication_token, receipt_image: "foo.png"
 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "foo.png"
```

how can pass the image in rspec code, i also tried @foo.png that is working with curl command.

Answer (score 6):

On model-level, you need to pass it an opened image:

```
@foo.image = File.open(Rails.root.join("spec", "fixtures", "sticker.jpg"))
@foo.save!
```

On controller level you pass it a String, path to the image. This is best an absolute path.

```
params[:foo][:image] = Rails.root.join("spec", "fixtures", "sticker.jpg")
post :new, params
```